# How exactly did Swami Vivekananda die?

Tags: history, yoga, death, vivekananda

Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swami_Vivekananda#Death):

> On 4 July 1902 (the day of his death) Vivekananda awoke early, went to the monastery at Belur Math and meditated for three hours. He taught Shukla-Yajur-Veda, Sanskrit grammar and the philosophy of yoga to pupils, later discussing with colleagues a planned Vedic college in the Ramakrishna Math. **At 7:00 p.m. Vivekananda went to his room, asking not to be disturbed; he died at 9:20 p.m. while meditating.**
>
> According to his disciples, Vivekananda attained mahasamādhi; the rupture of a blood vessel in his brain was reported as a possible cause of death. His disciples believed that the rupture was due to his brahmarandhra (an opening in the crown of his head) being pierced when he attained mahasamādhi.

[This article](https://www.hindustantimes.com/kolkata/swami-vivekananda-suffered-from-31-ailments/story-AzNd0vIynJOGkO5MJzW9AK.html) however says:

> The fateful evening of July 4, 1902, **Vivekananda passed away following a third heart attack**, completing 39 years, five months and 24 days.

I don't understand how one can one *plan* a heart attack on oneself. Is this possible through yoga?

Did Vivekananda have a history of heart problems?

Why do we have two different accounts of Vivekananda's death? What's the true story?

Comment: Don't have references off hand now hence the comment, Yogis can do that, happens all the time in Jain and Buddhist traditions as well. Raghupati yogi couple of decades backs induced a dozen "heart attacks" in a span of few hours before he decided to "leave" the body. He was from "Shastanga" yoga tradition which needs initiation by a "Guru"

Comment: yogis can choose when to die. they don't plan a 'heart attack'. they plan to separate the prana from the body through yoga. a symptom of that is the heart-stopping. if you have ever forcefully held your breath for a long time (2+ minutes), you'll feel an agony sensation near your groin (where the muladhara chakra sits) - because that is where prana starts to leave the body. if you learn to control it, you can make it rise upwards and make it leave through one of the 7 chakras.

Comment: Perhaps one must concentrate on how he lived!!

Answer (score 9):

There is a detailed chronology of the last day of Swami Vivekananda in the Bengali Best Seller 'Achena Ajana Vivekananda' by Sankar.

> 9:00 pm: The Swami was lying face up.He turned on his left side. For a
> few second his right hand shook slightly. There were beads of
> perspiration on his forehead. Then he began to cry like a baby.
>
> 9:02-9:10 pm: He exhaled a deep breath. He remained still for 2
> minutes and then he again exhaled a deep breadth. His head shook and
> then fell off from the pillow. His eyes became still and an unearthly
> glow began to emit from his smiling face.
>
> 9:30 pm: Everyone came running in thinking that the Swami has enetered
> Samadhi. Swami Bodhananda checked the pulse and then began crying. One
> person told someone to immediately bring Dr. Mahendra Majumdar to the
> Belur Math. Swamis Premananda and Nischayananda started to recite
> Ramakrishna's name in the Swami's ears to bring him down from Samadhi.
>
> 10:30 pm: Dr. Majumdar, Swamis Brahmananda and Saradananda came
> almost at the same time to Belur Math. Baikuntha Sanyal also came.
> Dr. Majumdar examined the body and saw the heart has stopped. He tried
> to artificially stimulate the heart.
>
> 12:am: Dr. Majumdar informed the inmates that the Swamiji has passed
> away. His diagnosis was that stoppage of the heart caused the death of
> the Swami.
>
> Vivekananda lived 39 years 5 months and 24 days. He has kept his word
> since he had told his intimates that he will not see 40.
>
> About 3 months before his death (28 March 1902) the Swami told his
> disciple Nivedita  that 'he has given everything that he could give.
> Now he will have to go'.
>
> Two days before his death he told his intimates that the spiritual
> power in Belur will create a powerful movement for 1500 years.
>
> Three days before his death (1st July 1902) while walking the grounds
> of the Belur Math the Swami showed his disciples a spot on the bank
> of the Ganga and told them to cremate his body there.

My free translation of Achena Ajana Vivekananda by Sankar.